# Laravel 6 CSS JS not loading on server

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, laravel-6

I zipped my project folder and uploaded to the `Document Root` for the subdomain. I have all my CSS and JS files inside the Public folder. On XAMPP it is working just fine, but when I upload it to my shared hosting, the css and js does not load. Upon clicking on the URLs generated for the css and js found on the `View Page Source`, I get `404 Not found`.

When I tried checking the Console tab in the Inspect Element option, I see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`error. But I double checked that the files are there in the folders as it were when working on XAMPP locally.

For refenrence, this is how I linked my css files

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" type="text/css">
```

PHP version of my server is `7.3.23` and my Laravel version is `6.18.42`.

Answer (score 2):

Check `APP_URL` in .env file. Is it correct and not "localhost"?

Try to use this (maybe it's not help, but it looks better anyway):

```
<link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: As far as I know, `{{ }}` and `<?php echo ?>` are the same thing, but I had tried both ways and the result is the same.

Comment: Maybe this `<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`? Does any css file works in your hosting?

Comment: That is the issue I am facing, if you read the question correctly. The CSS and JS files are not loading on my shared hosting. They are working fine on my localhost (XAMPP), but not my hosting.

Comment: I mean, not loading at all in any projects in hosting (not only that laravel project)? You can try to create just index.php and style.css, to check, if the problem with hosting or your project.

Comment: Also you can check `APP_URL` in .env file. Is it correct and not "localhost"?

Comment: It is working in other projects, but not this.

Comment: And what about my comment above?

Answer (score 0):

For this follow following step :-

1 ) set your APP_ASSET url like ASSET_URL=http://localhost:8000/public in to env. file.

2 ) and set html tag linke this <link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

1 ) set your APP_ASSET url like ASSET_URL=http://localhost:8000/public in to env. file.

this command helped me, however I wrote full name of the site with https